# Onedrive Rest API to access files and folders public without sign in with Ms Account

Tags: c#, asp.net, onedrive

I have an the public link as follow : https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=b1eb5f906f0dc16e&id=B1EB5F906F0DC16E%21103&ithint=folder,&authkey=!ADh77UVUy3x9dfQ

With this link I can access it on browsers without sign in with Ms Account. So can I use which Rest API to access files and folders without sign in with Ms Account?

Comment: http://onedrive.github.io/sdks.htm - these are your only Windows-endorsed options.

Answer (score 0):

Since, you have a public link there is no need to call any API's here.

Use WL.fileDialog method inside your javascript and select the file you want in the file picker window. you will get the file object as a response.

Attach the file.link property to wherever you want to attach and the file can be accessed globally.